# Not all search results displaying in listbox on userform

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have the below code which should show a dynamic column and row range based on a date find. This is in a userform and displays the results in a listbox. The issue I am having is it is only showing the first row there are 5 in the search range going off this month the top line displays and the next 4 are pulled through only they display as blank. Is anyone able to help at all so this shows all 5?

```
Private Sub CBtn_Find_Click()

Dim RNG As Range
Dim DATA As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim CNT, CLN As Integer

Set RNG = Sheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

ReDim DATA(1 To RNG.Rows.Count, 1 To RNG.Columns.Count)

For i = 1 To RNG.Rows.Count

On Error Resume Next
If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "D") >= CDate(Me.TB_StartDate) And Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "D") <= CDate(Me.TB_EndDate) Then
    CNT = CNT + 1
        For CLN = 1 To RNG.Columns.Count
        DATA(CNT + 1, CLN) = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, CLN)
    Next CLN
End If

Next i

Me.LB_Records.List = DATA
Me.LB_Records.ColumnCount = CLN

Me.LB_Records.AddItem
For x = 1 To CLN
    Me.LB_Records.List(0, x - 1) = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, x)
Next x
Me.LB_Records.Selected(0) = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `On Error Resume Next` in your code context? It only does  not let VBA showing where and what error may be... If errors are raised, you should correct the code to avoid them.

Comment: I have commented this out and I got the error "Could not set the List Property. Invalid Property Value highlighting the line Me.LB_Records.List(0, x - 1) = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, x). This makes no sense however as this is for the title bar at the top to pull through and this line of the code works

Comment: What value does `CLN` show when stopped on error (moving the cursor over it)?

Comment: It holds the value of 16.

Comment: And `x`? Is it what you think it should be?

Comment: Yes its right ona also at 16

Comment: This means that the iteration went up to 16 and column 15 has a problem. I remember something about a columns limitation using this method. Please, try instead iteration, to load it from an array, something like: `Me.LB_Records.List = Sheets("Data").Range(Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Data").Cells(1, CLN).Value`. Comment  `Me.LB_Records.AddItem`, too. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @FaneDuru I have just solved. The issue was with the date range in column D had been knocked to a text format rather than a date.

Comment: Good that you solved it, but please, try the method I suggested above. Loading a list box without iteration is faster, safer, more compact...